# What is up with this user?

Tags: support, status-completed, specific-question, spam

There is a particular user who seems to be posting really weird, unrelated "answers" to a [particular question](https://superuser.com/questions/702371/how-can-i-view-the-exif-orientation-of-a-photo-in-photoshop). The answers seem to contain HTML code that is supposed to generate spam, in my opinion. Additionally, I saw another answer to the question which seems to me like an unsolicited advertisement and is thus spam too. Therefore, all the answers on the question effectively qualify as spam. I didn't know what to do with them, so I flagged the answers as such. Additionally, here is the link to the (unregistered) user: https://superuser.com/users/290817/chenchuanwen

Can these answers be deleted and the user destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't/don't block IPs, too many false positives with that. I've destroyed the user.

Comment: I've read somewhere in the help center a while ago that IPs are blocked in some cases. Are such blocks no longer implemented?

Comment: And why is the fourth answer not an unsolicited advertisement?

Comment: One more question: Should the question be protected too?

Comment: @gparyani there is an internal spam monitoring system that may restrict contributions from certain IPs, but it cannot be manually activated by moderators. We aren't able to provide any public details about the system, to prevent spammers gaming it.

Comment: @nhinkle Do you think the question should be protected? I mean, I know that each user is only considered once for the 3 deleted answers from new users criteria for being protected by Community.

Comment: there's no need to protect right now. If required, [question will get auto-protected](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/89971/133693). it was random spam from one user trying to spam.

Comment: @Sathya As I said in the last comment, the question seems to target spam, but the 3 deleted answers are just considered one since they were posted by the same author for protection by Community.

Comment: I mean, I'm not *asking* for protection. I'm just asking if it is a good idea.

Comment: What about my second comment? Why is the fourth answer not an unsolicited advertisement? Seems like one to me, but my spam flag is listed as "declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it" in my flag history. Why is that?

Comment: @gparyani because it isn't an unsolicited advertisement. It's not the right answer, but it's not spam either. Spam flags are reserved for strictly unsolicited, or out of scope posts or blatant ads. The other answer isn't one. Use downvotes for such.

Comment: @Sathya SPAM flags are also used against trolls...

Comment: @Braiam err.. no, that should _never_ be the case. If there's something offense, use the offensive flag. If trolling probably use the custom mod flag. Spam is strictly for spammers.

Comment: @Sathya [Tim don't think so](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8086/169736):  you should definitely not flag something as spam that is not a blatant advertisement or **purely nonsensical trolling attempt of some sort**.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [XSS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attempts to me. The text of the posts is actually JavaScript code, and it seems the user was trying to harvest user data. These 10k-only links should make that clear: [1](https://superuser.com/revisions/7a51f12b-49a3-413d-9976-e8bc3e26f2c0/view-source) [2](https://superuser.com/revisions/a2aa7271-56d9-4659-9428-d1fefdcd38ee/view-source) [3](https://superuser.com/revisions/1873da08-0819-4181-a684-b132d911c2d0/view-source)

Here's one of them (URL removed):

```javascript
var message = "<a href='(...)'>(...) message);
                dicParam.MyAdd("display-name", base.Nickname);
                dicParam.MyAdd("m-address", base.Email);
                string i1lUrl = GetRequestUrl("/questions/ticks");
                string i1l = HttpHelper.Get(i1lUrl, puri).Body;
                dicParam.MyAdd("i1l", i1l);
                dicParam.Remove("legalLinksShown");
```

Comment: Can you include some screenshots not uploaded using Imgur?

Comment: @gparyani why not Imgur?

Comment: It's blocked in my local network.

Comment: Permanent OneDrive link for reference: http://1drv.ms/1duHQup